# C# Console Application - Running Node JS Script Files

Tags: c#, node.js, console-application

I have a C# Console Application that Structures Data stored within a Staging MongoDB Collection, before I can stage there are some Node JS Scripts that scrape this Data, I'm trying to automate this process by having the C# Console Application run each of the Script Files then the Structuring Process.

I'm not sure how to approach this, most of the examples provided use Edge which only allows you to run a piece of code not a Node JS File (This is my Understanding from examples I've seen).

These Node JS Scripts do use imports so there is a node_modules.

The final outcome I'm looking for is something like this,

- Started Scraping
- Running Script 1 (Node JS Script)
- Running Script 2 (Node JS Script)
- Finished Running Scripts
- Started Structuring
- Structured Collection 1 (C# Process)
- Structured Collection 2 (C# Process)

Answer (score 0):

you could use **node-cmd** module for this **https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cmd** .

Execute the C# process command via **node-cmd**, at the end of the nodejs scripting response.

Comment: My current issue is being able to run a Node JS Script from a C# Console Application

Comment: @SandroPerez how did you solve this. are you able to run node js script from c# console app